# How to make a sticky sidebar float only within a parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

pls I used the this jquery code to make my sidebar sticky, but it floats to the footer of the page and covers it, pls how can I make stop at the bottom of the parent container  (ie outer-wrapper)

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebarfo"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 170;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Sorry, I couldn't get the code to work on jsfiddle, I could have uploaded it, but the live example can be found here: http://www.wilburtech.com. Pls Scroll down the page to the "Follow us" widget.

I got the script from https://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/

So far the only step I have taken is to use `z-index` to hide it behind the footer.

Comment: you should disable it, in mobile mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 15;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top
              && $window.scrollTop() < $('footer').offset().top

       ) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
```

add the line above, it will only animate if your window scroll postion is less than footer postion.

you need to change the selector to match your website, plus add any number to that value to have a little padding.

hope this help

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. Though I actually don't understand the syntax of your code totally, the main problem is from desktop not on mobile. I wanted to make the sticky sidebar stop at the bottom of    #outer-wrapper (before the advert above the footer). Please, I would like you to expatiate on your answer, as I would also like to disable the plugin on mobile as an added feature.

Comment: Desk top looks ok in chrome. Can you explain your problem again?

Comment: Scroll down till you get to the footer of the page. The "Follow Us" widget floats down and hides behind the advert and right-most footer widget. I wanted it to stop floating and not exceed that page navigation. Please see this image for better understanding http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4Z8QBS3-1v0/Val-aaArrII/AAAAAAAABTI/H7OBVTHVzd0/s1600/Screenshot%2B%2528310%2529.png

Comment: thanks for the help but it still didn't work, the sidebar still floats and hides behind the footer. Pls is there another option?

Comment: This the styles od the
    #footer-widgets-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#sidebarfo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
}

#outer-wrapper (the parent container) {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 2px auto 0;
  padding-top: 125px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;}

Answer (score 0):

I would try making use of .scrollHeight() and setting your $window.scroll to use a range, maybe something like this:

```
    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebarfo"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 170,
        footerHeight = XXX;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top < ($window.scrollHeight() - footerHeight)) {
           //animation stuff.
           }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but I tried that and the sidebar stopped scrolling all together!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a plugin for this kind of blocks, that follow the scroll.

You can get the source on [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/halfzebra/jquery-sptayplease/master/src/jquery.stayPlease.js)

You will have to specify the following options:

```
$('#sidebarfo').stayPlease({'until': '#Blog1 .date-posts:last'});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.i-wanna-stay').stayPlease({
      'until': '.the-edge',
      'offset': '10px'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/halfzebra/jquery-sptayplease/master/src/jquery.stayPlease.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 the-edge">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="well i-wanna-stay">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
          <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="bs-docs-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="container well" style="padding-top: 700px">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Maybe, I didn't apply it well, because what happens is that when I load the page, the sidebar in question appears but as soon as I start scrolling, it disappears all together.

Comment: @Wilbersoft this is a bug that I have overlooked, I'll fix it asap, thanks for feedback